# Regex issue for decimal field - Swift

Tags: swift, regex

I am trying to implement a regex for decimal numbers such that it allows:

- upto 10 digits before decimal point
- upto 2 digits after decimal point
- should not be `0`
- can be `>= 0.01`

I have tried this: `static let decimalRegex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^(?!(0))\\d{0,10}(\\.$|\\.\\d{0,2}$|$)", options: [])`

It does not let me type in `0` so to denote `0.01` I enter `.01` in the textfield. When I re-populate the same in the textfield on edit, it shows as `0.01` but i am unable to delete/edit/insert anything in it.

Please help so that all the conditions above can be met through regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using

```
"^(?![0.]+$)[0-9]{0,10}(?:\\.[0-9]{0,2})?$"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/19OJWE/4)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?![0.]+$)` - up to the end of string, there can't be only zeros and/or dots
- `[0-9]{0,10}` - zero to ten digits
- `(?:\\.[0-9]{0,2})?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\\.` - a dot
  - `[0-9]{0,2}` - zero or two digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I am unable to enter decimal point at all if i input `1111`

Comment: @Mamta Actually, I also thought about making the digits after `.` optional by using `{0,2}` instead of `{1,2}`.

Comment: The lookahead is the culprit in your case. Let me think.

Comment: I think you can't use a single regex approach here then. Use `^[0-9]{0,10}(?:\\.[0-9]{0,2})?$` and check if the value of the whole input is not zero. Or use a second regex check then.

Comment: Thanks. `check if the value of the whole input is not zero` this suggestion did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer by @Wiktor have you thought about other edge cases

the regex `^(?![.0]+$)[0-9]{0,10}(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$` [try it here](https://regex101.com/r/O3PDxi/2)

will match:

```
1
1.
1.12
01
0123456789
1234567890.12
0000000001
012.00
0.01
.01
```

but will not match:

```
0
-0
-0.0
0.0
1.123
12345678900
01234567890
1.000
1.001
1.1.
.1.1
-123
-0123.45
-0.01
```

Comment: Isn't allowing me to input `0.01`

Comment: Ah so i guess you are using the regex as validation in a field that you type into? so once you press the 0 key the regex blocks the input? can't you just apply the regex when you tab out of the field? I know my regex but i know nothing about swift!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need the regex to be applied while I am typing itself

Comment: In this case you cant disallow 0 or 0. as you need to type these in order to get to 0.01 unless you force your users to type backwards ;-) (first type 1 then left arrow, then 0.0)